# Can we kill the ubuntu14.04 tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

the [ubuntu14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu14.04) tag has been used 16 times and it shouldn't even had been created. It should be linked as a duplicate to 14.04 or just burned from the system.

Comment: Done. Thanks for pointing it out.